# Printing a literal string python in octal

Tags: python, string, hex, literals, octal

Hi I am having trouble trying to print a literal string in a proper format.
For starters i have an object with a string parameter which is used for metadata such that it looks like:

```
obj {
    metadata: <str>
}
```

The object is being returned as a protocol response and we have the object to use as such.

print obj gives:

```
    metadata: "\n)\n\022foobar"
```

When I print the obj.metadata python treats the value as a string and converts the escapes to linebreaks and the corresponding ascii values as expected.

When i tried 
print repr(obj.metadata)

```
"\n)\n\x12foobar"
```

Unfortunately python prints the literal but converts the escaped characters from octal to hex. Is there a way i can print the python literal with the escaped characters in octal or convert the string such that I can have the values printed as it is in the object?

Thanks for the help

The extremely bad solution I have so far is

```
print str(obj).rstrip('\"').lstrip('metadata: \"')
```

to get the correct answer, but i am assuming there must be a smarter way

TLDR:

```
x = "\n)\n\022foobar"
print x

)
foobar

print repr(x)
'\n)\n\x12foobar'
```

how do i get x to print the way it was assigned

Comment: How are you reading that data?

Comment: We get the data as a part of a response packet from server. We have the object definitions and thus can interact with it by using field names. Not sure if that answers the question

Comment: When you say "object" do you mean a `dict`?

Comment: Possible relevant: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0223/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
print('\\\n)\\\n\\\022foobar')
```

or

```
print(r'\n)\n\022foobar')
```

The escape character '\' interprets the character following it differently, for example `\n` is used for new line.

The double escape character '\\' or letter 'r' nullifies the interpretation of the escape character. This is similar in C language.

Comment: This might be a good answer but it is not clear. It would be nice if you can provide some text why this is the solution to the problem.

Comment: `Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.`, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - also please format your code.